# Change title of embed with data:application/pdf;base64 source

Tags: c#, html, pdf, embed

For a project, I'm using the HTML embed element to display a PDF to users. First I'll generate my PDF and then save it on the server before passing it to the embed. However, I have a very large number of PDFs being generated, so my server's disk space is quickly saturated. While searching, I saw that you could pass the PDF converted to base 64. This works perfectly, but I have a problem with the file name. As you can see on the screenshot, I have base64 displayed as the file name.

[image]

My question is, is it possible to change this title to a custom value that I define myself? I've already tried adding the title or donwload tags in the embed but it doesn't change anything. Below is the HTML code I'm currently using.

```
<embed src="my-base64-pdf" width="100%" height="1000px" type="application/pdf" title="My custom title PDF" download="my-pdf.pdf">
```

Thanks.